# How to range query a date mapped as long

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an external ES db (i.e. I can't change its structure) with the following mapping

```
      "failure_url": {
        "properties": {
          "lastAccessTime": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "url": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
     }
```

lastAccessTime represents a date, but is mapped as a long. A standard "range" filter fails with

```
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "number_format_exception",
        "reason": "For input string: "now""
      }
```

is the error in my filter expression or is it due to the field not being a "date"? If the latter, how can I still query this date?

Comment: You could still query the date but you'll have to do the date math yourself then just have a "normal" number range query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query your field with `now` and other [date match expressions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math), then your field must be defined as a `date` type.

One thing you can do is to create another field of type date and then update your index to index that new field.

So first change your mapping like this:

```
PUT my-index/_mappings
{
  "properties": {
    "lastAccessDate": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can leverage the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) in order to index your dates from the long field:

```
POST my-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.lastAccessDate = ctx._source.lastAccessTime"
  }
}
```

When that's done, you'll be able to run your `range` query on the new `lastAccessDate` field of type `date`.

Comment: thanks, but being an external database I can't add mappings. I am looking for a way of converting it to date, then using the "now" notation in the query

Comment: Please explain how you send the data to Elasticsearch from your database?